# Login page is redirecting to homepage

Tags: url-rewriting

Unable to login because `wp-login.php` redirects to **homepage**.

I tried deactivating all plugins but nothing worked.

I didn't install any plugins or make any changes recently.

Comment: Well something changed.  If you pull the site down to a local development environment does the problem persist?  Some plugins can still leave changes even after they're disabled.  Did you try with a default theme?

Comment: I am unable to login into admin panel. login page redirects to homepage. I tried disabling plugins and themes unsing ftp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your DOMAIN site.

Put this in your `wp-config.php` file

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Probably thats fix your problem.
Wherever, you can revert back to the Default Theme, renaming the folder of your current theme in `/wp-content/themes/` directory.

Trying too deleting your `.htaccess` file

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was that the permissions were not set to 755 on the wp-admin folder.